# Pass by reference stumps newbie

Tags: java, extends

According to the javadocs "A subclass inherits all the members (fields, methods, and nested classes) [from its superclass](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html)". Also, [Java manipulates objects by](http://www.javaworld.com/javaqa/2000-05/03-qa-0526-pass.html) reference So why does this subclass return the wrong value for aList[0] ? It seems each class is modifying their own array when I expect them to both modify the same array.

```
public class mystery {
protected List<String> aList;

public mystery() {
    aList = new ArrayList<String>();
}

public void addToArray() {
    //"foo" is successfully added to the arraylist
    aList.add("foo");
}

public void printArray() {
    System.out.println( "printArray " + aList.get(0) +"" );
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    mystery prob1 = new mystery();
    mysterySubclass prob2 = new mysterySubclass();
    //add "foo" to array
    prob1.addToArray();
    //add "bar" to array
    prob2.addToArray2();

    //expect to print "foo", works as expected
    prob1.printArray();
    //expect to print "foo", but actually prints "bar"
    prob2.printArray();
    //expect to print "foo", but actually prints "bar"
    prob2.printArray2();
}
```

}

```
public class mysterySubclass extends mystery {

public void mysterySubclass() {}
public void addToArray2() {
    aList.add("bar");
}

public void printArray2() {
    System.out.println( "printArray2 " + super.aList.get(0) +"" );
}
```

}

Comment: You never call `addToArray()` on `prob2`, so how do you expect it to magically have `foo` somewhere in the list? Also, `printArray` and `printArray2` do the same thing: there's a single underlying list for every instance of `mysterySubclass`.

Comment: This also has nothing to do with pass by reference: you aren't passing anything to any of your methods. And if you've paid attention to the article you linked to, it explicitly states Java doesn't pass anything by reference; although it passes references by value. There's a subtle but important difference between the two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    mystery prob1 = new mystery();
    mysterySubclass prob2 = new mysterySubclass();
```

Here you are creating **two new objects**, so they will have their own list and wont share one as you expect.

What you are looking for is:

```
    mystery prob1 = new mysterySubclass();
    mysterySubclass prob2 = (mysterySubclass)prob1;
```

Try this..

Comment: also mark that `printArray2()` you are using super, but ain't required.

Comment: as @Luiggi Mendoza says try using debugger and find it out yourself. And your problem has nothing to do with Pass By Reference.

Comment: Doing this way you have two different references to the same object and then when you manipulate the list using methods, they both will add to the same list.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're calling `prob2.addToArray2();` that would add `"bar"` String to the `aList` attribute in the `prob2` variable. Take into account that they share same attributes, not the same reference to the object reference, so each `prob` and `prob2` have their own `aList` attribute value. This behavior can be easily proven using a debugger.

Comment: So it sounds like even though a child class has access to the parent's fields, it does not have the same references. so mysterySubclass gets it's own "aList" instead of referring to the parents aList object. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @user1626687 you're welcome. Don't forget to mark the best answer with the green check (mine or `@Narendra`'s, that's up to you).

Answer (score 0):

```
mystery prob1 = new mystery();
mysterySubclass prob2 = new mysterySubclass();
//add "foo" to array
prob1.addToArray();
//add "bar" to array
prob2.addToArray2();

//expect to print "foo", works as expected
prob1.printArray();
//expect to print "foo", but actually prints "bar"
prob2.printArray();
//expect to print "foo", but actually prints "bar"
prob2.printArray2();
```

your prob1 has aList
your prob2 has aList
and yes, they are different.

after 4th line => prob1.aList -- foo

after 6th line => prob2.aList -- bar

so prob2.printArray() has only "bar" to print and also prob2.printArray2()
basically they do the same thing.